# How to use array.push to add value to an array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a value with array.push to my first element of array [0] to the field yesterday, I don't know very well what the structure is to be able to add this value. try the following way

```
var cumpleaños = [
  {
    ayer: "",
  },
  {
    hoy: "12-07-20",
}  ,
  {
    mañana: "12-08-20"
}
];
cumpleaños.push([0].ayer.("12-06-20"))
console.log(cumpleaños[0].ayer)
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: array.push is to add elements to an array

Comment: Looks like you just have to do the following: cumpleaños[0].ayer = "12-06-20";

Comment: This looks like you've chosen the wrong data organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do assignment to the first element of the array. (If the oder is always the same)

```
cumpleaños[0].ayer = "12-06-20"
```

Comment: `.[0]` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to push anything since you're not adding a new value, you're just modifying an existing value:

```js
cumpleaños[0].ayer = "12-06-20";
```

As a side note, your data structure would be much more effectively represented by a single object not inside an array:

```js
const cumpleaños = {
    ayer: "12-06-20",
    hoy: "12-07-20",
    mañana: "12-08-20"
};
```